# drupal 7, paths and urls are not working properly

Tags: uri

I'm developing a website on my localhost. I have a problem with urls.

for a url like this

```
http://localhost:81/my_website/library
```

I should output image src this way :

```
<img src="<?php print $directory; ?>/image/header/headerR.png"/>
```

but when the above url is changed to this

```
http://localhost:81/my_website/library/
```

I should output image src this way :

```
<img src="../<?php print $directory; ?>/image/header/headerR.png"/>
```

I mean it should refer to the parent. my website has also contextual filter which must be inserted after **library/** .is there any general solution for handling such thing?

Comment: Why don't you use these global variables: $base_path or $base_url for your stuff.

Comment: I tested $base_path and the same problem happened

Comment: Do you remove the comment of this line `$base_url = 'http://www.example.com'` in **settings.php** and change the `www.example.com` by your domain. It should be like  `$base_url = 'http://localhost:81/my_website';` in your **settings.php** file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [global variables](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals) for resolving the issue of path of files as below:

1. Use [base_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7) if your fine with domain name not to be included:
   It will return path respect to the drupal root.
   Eg:  "/" for drupal root(`http://localhost:81/my_website`), and
   "/images/header" for `http://localhost:81/my_website/image/header/header`

   Example:

   > ```
   > /*Assuming image path: http://localhost:81/my_website/image/header/headerR.png*/
   > global $base_path; /* will return "/" for http://localhost:81/my_website*/
   > $image_path = $base_path . 'image/header/headerR.png';
   > ```

   **Note**: Don't use trailing slash `/` for adding path of files with **$base_path** as it adds a "/" to the beginning and end of the returned path.
2. Use [base_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7) if you want to get the full path: It will return
   base URL of the Drupal installation.

   Example:

   > ```
   > /*Assuming image path: http://localhost:81/my_website/image/header/headerR.png*/
   > global $base_url; /* will return http://localhost:81/my_website in you case*/
   > $image_path = $base_url . '/image/header/headerR.png';
   > ```